# How does a form field in the view become associated with an object in the model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, model

This is a two part question.  First, I understand that if use this in my Model:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.CustomerSatisfactionSurvey), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Page1Question1Required")]
    public int? LikelyToReturn { get; set; }
```

And then this in my View:

```
@for (var c = 0; c < 11; c++)
    {
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.LikelyToReturn, @c)
    }
```

That I have now created an association between the object in the model "LikelyToReturn" and the radio button group by the same name in the view. When the user selects a radio button and clicks the Submit button, the model is updated, and LikelyToReturn is filled with the selected value. That happens without me having to specifically emaciate the two.

**Question 1:** How and why does that work?  I'm thinking it has to do with the [Required...] tag, but I'd like to be sure.

**Question 2:** How would one create such an association with the field is NOT required?  I have other model variables & form fields that have matching names, but are not required, and they are not associated automatically.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your `[Required]` attribute. When you submit a form, a series of name/value pairs are sent back to your controller method based on the `name` attribute of your form controls (`input`, `select` and `textarea` elements).

In your case you have a radio button group (your generating 11 controls with `<input type="radio" name="LikelyToReturn" ... />`) with values 0 - 10. If you select the 3rd radio button and submit, the posted form data will be `LikelyToReturn: 2`.

On the controller side, the `DefaultModelBinder` is responsible for reading the form data (and other values such as route data) and matching up the posted values with your model properties. If your model contains a property named `LikelyToReturn` then its value will be set to `2`.

The `[Required]` attribute is a validation attribute and is used to validate your property. In your case, if you manually included an additional radio button

```
<input type="radio" name="LikelyToReturn" value="" />
```

and selected it, then validation would fail because it would set `LikelyToReturn=null;` and an error would be added to `ModelState`

If you have other properties in your model that are not being bound, then it is most likely because (1) the `name` attribute of the control does not match your property name, which is why you should always use the strongly typed html helpers to generate the html in your forms, or (2) your trying to bind to fields rather than properties (i.e. no `{ get; set; }`)